# NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovy.xml.jaxb.JaxbGroovyMethods due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, java-9, java-11

Our Gradle build have  `--add-modules=java.xml.bind,java.activation,java.xml.ws.annotation` to `options.compilerArgs` in `JavaCompile` to build with JDK9/10. That works great right now, but these modules are deprecated.

I want to prepare for JDK11 where [these modules might be removed](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).

I have tried adding `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0`, `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0` and `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0` to `compile` and `runtime` as well as `classpath` in `buildscript`, but I still get `NoClassDefFoundError`.

What am I missing?

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':my-client:compileGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:596)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovy.xml.jaxb.JaxbGroovyMethods due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:175)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerCallable.call(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:76)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:42)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:30)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:101)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
        ... 3 more
```

The reported missing class isn't 100% identical for each build: it switches between complaining about `javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext`,  `javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller` and `javax/xml/bind/Marshaller`.

Comment: I cannot tell you how to properly fix your issue but I can propose a workaround: set your `JDK_JAVAC_OPTIONS` environment variable to `--add-modules java.xml.bind`

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Using `--add-modules` works perfectly fine, but that doesn't work in jdk11.  I want to replace the deprecated modules with library dependencies instead, but the `compileGroovy` task doesn't seem to find them on the classpath.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov `--add-modules java.xml.bind` shouldn't be required with JDK/11, right? Moreover, neu242, did you check http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320? Would be good to see the `build.gradle` dependencies you are using.

Comment: @neu242 I know next to nothing about Gradle, so these are all guesses... I can think of up to three moving parts that might need these dependencies: (a) The Gradle process itself, (b) the process launched for compilation, (c) the sources that are being compiled. I would guess that (b) is the case here - are you sure you've added these JARs to (b)? I would run Gradle with full debug output and hope to find out where exactly these JARs show up.

Comment: @neu242 Just a guess: if you put JAXB jars to `gradle/lib`, will it work?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Nope, that didn't work :(

Comment: @Nicolai I've added the dependencies to `dependencies { compile(...) }`, but that doesn't seem to cut it.

Comment: @neu242 Did you run with full debug output? If you did that with Maven, it would show you the exact class paths that are used for each process. That would at least answer the question, whether the JARs end up in the right place.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but with Groovy 2.5.0. I tried the `--add-modules` approach for all tasks with type `AbstractCompile`, but unfortunately that's not working either. I hope you found a solution

Comment: For those with enough points and like to work on groovy - please vote for re-opening the question.  This is very special bug and was fixed in 2.5.1/2.5.2 to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this solved itself, possibly due new newer Groovy (2.5.1) and Gradle (4.7) dependencies.

Comment: What was the groovy version? 2.5.2?

Comment: At the time of writing I was on Groovy 2.5.0 and Gradle 4.7.   When it was solved I was on Groovy 2.5.1 and Gradle 4.10.

Comment: That is correct. 2.5.1 was created to fix the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This line in `build.gradle` dependencies solved this exact problem to me:

```
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
```

Comment: But not for me :(  I wonder what's wrong with my setup...